# apply color to each face/vertex with opacity /alpha using Shader material three.js

Tags: three.js

Here I try to render a cube/plane geometry using `THREE.ShaderMaterial` with `THREE.ShaderLib['lambert']`, it loaded perfectly, but I am struggling to change each face color with opacity value.

Comment: You want to have different opacities for each face (different materials) ? or all faces the same opacity ? (same material)

Comment: thanks vincent. we can apply opacity to material, but my need is to apply alpha to vertex or opacity to face, iam assuming that it can achieve by only vertexshader and fragementshader method onl.

Comment: Little brainstorming and workout made me to achieve it.Thanks All.

Comment: could you post your solution? thanks :)

Comment: @vinni check the examples "https://threejs.org/examples/?q=att#webgl_custom_attributes_points3"  add color attributes as follows for rgb => geometry.addAttribute( 'ca', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );, rgba => geometry.addAttribute( 'ca', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 4 ) );

Answer (score 1):

As of Three.js 0.127 you can simply use `vertexColors`, and it supports alpha (opacity) values.

On your material, set

```
material.vertexColors = true
```

On your geometry make sure you set the itemSize to include alpha,

```
geometry.attributes.color.itemSize === 4
```

then provide 4 values (RGBA) for each vertex instead of 3 (RGB).

Docs:

- [`Material.vertexColors`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=material#api/en/materials/Material.vertexColors)
- [`ShaderMaterial.vertexColors`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=shadermaterial#api/en/materials/ShaderMaterial.vertexColors)

Example usage:

[webgl_geometry_colors](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_colors.html)

Note, the example uses itemSize 3, without opacity. Make sure you use itemSize 4, and for every value provide 4 numbers instead of 3.